# Most efficient way to use an array of objects to query more objects - MongoDb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

If I have a controller like this:

```
const Review = require('../models/review')
const Launch = require('../models/launch')

async function getReviewsByUserId (req, res) {
  const { userId } = req.params

  const reviews = await Review.find({ userId }).lean() || []

  return res.status(200).send(reviews.reverse())
}
```

How can I use the returned `reviews` to query more objects in the fastest way possible? Example of what I mean:

```
async function getReviewsByUserId (req, res) {
  const { userId } = req.params

  const reviews = await Review.find({ userId }).lean() || []

  let launches = []
  for (review in reviews) {
    let launch = await Launch.find({launchId: review.launchId})
    launches.push(launch)
  }

  return res.status(200).send(launches.reverse())
}
```

So as you can see, I simply loop though all my `reviews` and then use the `review.launchId` to lookup launches and push each to an array and return that.

Is this efficient? Is there a faster way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @Tiago Bértolo's answer seems good.  Alternatively consider combining the two `find()`s into a single `aggregate()` that uses `$lookup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the operator [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to find multiple elements by `launchId`.

```
async function getReviewsByUserId (req, res) {
  const { userId } = req.params

  const reviews = await Review.find({ userId }).lean() || []

  let launches = []
  const reviewLaunchIds = reviews.map(review => review.launchId)
  let launch = await Launch.find({launchId:{ $in: reviewLaunchIds })

  return res.status(200).send(launch)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [aggregate pipelines](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) would be faster and more efficient but a little complicated to use.

The query could be achieved by:

```js
async function getReviewsByUserId(req, res) {
  const { userId } = req.params;

  const launches = await Review.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        userId
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "launches",
        localField: "launchId",
        foreignField: "launchId",
        as: "launches"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$launches",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
      }
    },
    { $group: { _id: "$launches._id", data: { $first: "$$ROOT" } } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data.launches" } }
  ]);

  return res.status(200).send(launches.reverse());
}
```